# How can I simplify and shortify these NGINX Rewrite Rules?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following **NGINX Rewrite Rules:**

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?a=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/?$ /page.php?b=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(a|b)/?$ /page.php?c=$1 last;

rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /page.php?a=$1&b=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/(a|b)/?$ /page.php?a=$1&c=$2 last;

rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/(a|b)/?$ /page.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 last;
```

And as you can see, page can have the parameters:

- `a` ***or*** `b` ***or*** `c`
- `a` **and** `b` ***or*** `a` **and** `c`
- `a` **and** `b` **and** `c`

But writing for each page **6** *lines* would be a little bet overwork, Since I assumed that `NGINX` has something to deal with such scheme of Rewrite Rules,

I would like to know How to **simplify** such set of Rules and How it works if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is happy with empty parameters, you can make each capture (together with its leading `/`) optional.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([0-9]+))?(?:/(a|b))?/?$ /page.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 last;
```

The non-capturing group `(?:  )` together with a trailing `?` makes it optional, and encloses the leading `/` and one of your captures.

One side-effect that you will need to protect against, is where all three captures are missing - i.e. the root URI `/`.

See [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) on non-capturing groups.

Comment: I never understood the usage of the `(?:)` tbh, What is the different between it and the usual `()`? I tried the same `RegEx` you wrote but without the `?:` and it worked same as the one with it, But what is the different here? Out of that, the Rule worked perfectly.

Comment: Use non-capturing groups to avoid assigning them to `$` variables. If you use `()` instead - it just means that the rewritten query string will change to `?a=$2&b=$4&c=$6`

Comment: I understand now after trying it, I would like to ask, How do I prevent the empty parameters if I don't want them?